# Rails - simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I use simple_form gem in my Rails app. When I use code like this

```
= f.input_field :name, label: false, placeholder: 'Name'
= f.input_field :price, label: false, placeholder: 'Price'
= f.input_field :description, label: false, placeholder: 'Description'
= f.input_field :image, label: false, placeholder: 'Image'
```

I get HTML for input:

```
<input class="string required textform" id="item_name" label="false" maxlength="255" name="item[name]" placeholder="Имя" size="255" type="text">
```

As you can see size of input is 255 now. Actually it's much more than enough. How can specify the size of inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is from simple_form documentation [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#usage)

> It is also possible to pass any html attribute straight to the input,
>   by using the :input_html option, for instance:
>
> ```
> <%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
>   <%= f.input :username, input_html: { class: 'special' } %>
>   <%= f.input :password, input_html: { maxlength: 20 } %>
>   <%= f.input :remember_me, input_html: { value: '1' } %>
>   <%= f.button :submit %>
> <% end %>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

To set size of `100` for `name` input:

```
= f.input :name, label: false, placeholder: 'Name', input_html: { size: 100 }
```